# split specific text from element by simple script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, split

Trying to split specific text from element. Given js it working, how to make short/simple this js?

*Element html example:*

```
<div id="ReviewBox">
<span>(By:) Hello</span>

<div id="ReviewBox">
 <span>By: Goodbye</span>
</div>

</div>
```

*JS:*

```
$('#ReviewBox span:contains("By:")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("(").join(""));
    $(this).html($(this).html().split(")").join(""));
});
```

Please Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xSphc/60/

How to make short/simple this js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function), also you should use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regular expression to remove `(` and `)`

```
$('#ReviewBox span:contains("By:")').html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/[/(\)]/g, '');
});
```

```js
$('#ReviewBox span:contains("By:")').html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/[/(\)]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReviewBox">
  <span>(By:) Hello</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q98bz19f/)

Comment: nice solution @Satpal deserve +1

Answer (score 1):

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xSphc/61/)

Apply with single split operation `/[/(\)]/g`

```js
 $('#ReviewBox span:contains("By:")').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().split(/[/(\)]/g).join(""));
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ReviewBox">
<span>(By:) Hello</span>

<div id="ReviewBox">
 <span>By: Goodbye</span>
</div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression `/[/(\)]/g`

```
$('#ReviewBox span:contains("By:")').each(function(){

    $(this).html($(this).html().split(/[/(\)]/g).join(""));

});
```

here is working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/xSphc/62/